# Create a random name for the complete script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that joins several `csv` files into an output file called `merged_t*.csv`

Here is the script:

```
for i in $(ls -latr sample_*.csv); 
do  
    paste -d, $i >> out_$RANDOM.csv;
done

sed 's/^|$/\x27/g' out_$RANDOM.csv | paste -d, > merged_t$RANDOM.csv
```

The `"$RANDOM"` in the first command `"out_$RANDOM"` must be the same that the `"out_$RANDOM"` in the second.

How can i do it?

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your own variable first:

```
myrandom=$RANDOM
for i in $(ls -latr sample_*.csv); do
    paste -d, $i >> out_${myrandom}.csv;
done
sed 's/^|$/\x27/g' out_${myrandom}.csv | paste -d, > merged_t${myrandom}.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

use the command that already solve your problem: **mktemp**

```
csv=$(mktemp out_XXXXXXXXXX.csv) 
for i in $(ls -latr sample_*.csv); 
do  
    paste -d, $i >> ${csv};
done

sed 's/^|$/\x27/g' ${csv} | paste -d, > merged_t${csv}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ipor Sircer already answered you correctly. The solution is to save the value of `$RANDOM` into a variable.

To explain why your question had a bug-

Each time you call `$RANDOM`, it does exactly what it is supposed to- generate a random number. So if you call it multiple times, it will generate different random numbers. So each calling of it will result in a different name. However when you call it once and save it in a variable, it can no longer change (since it has only been called the one time).

`$RANDOM` is not the best way to generate random numbers though. To test this, you can do the following-

```
for j in {1..500} 
do 
    for i in {1..1000} 
    do 
        echo "$RANDOM"
   done | awk '{a+=$1} END {print a/NR}' 
done
```

What this small script does is generate a thousand $RANDOM outputs (inner loop) and then take the average of the 1000 numbers. It does this 500 times in this example (outer loop). You will see that the averages over any thousand iterations of `$RANDOM` are quite similar to each other (all around 16000). This shows that there isn't very good variation being observed in the different times you call it.

Better ways include the `awk` `srand` command.